# Tensorflow: imported ops always result in "None" despite valid input & kernel

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to do following:

- a) define model graph
- b) initiate the model and train it for a very
  limited NUMBER_OF_PRE_ITERATIONS (let's say,
  NUMBER_OF_PRE_ITERATIONS=20). Save the model.
- c) repeat point b)
  NUMBER_OF_PRE_RUNS times (e.g. NUMBER_OF_PRE_RUNS=3). Each time, if a
  "new" model gives better results than the "saved" one, "new" model
  gets saved.

As a result of c), I should have a model with (probably) best initial values out of NUMBER_OF_PRE_RUNS models.

- d) import the "saved" (probably) best model and proceed with training.

PROBLEM: every time, all ops of the imported model result in "None" value.
Input figures seem valid, kernel & bias parameters as well. No "None" or any other suspicious figures there, just float numbers. So why "None" as result of every op?

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
# imports
# declarations of variables etc.

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.variable_scope(name_or_scope='Model_', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    x = tf.placeholder(...)
    y = tf.placeholder(...)
    input_layer = tf.layers.dense(...)
    inter_layer = tf.layers.dense(...)
    output_layer = tf.layers.dense(...)

    loss_funct = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y - output_layer), name='loss_f')
    optimit = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='optimit')
    train = optimit.minimize(loss=loss_funct, name='train')


saver = tf.train.Saver()

best_pre_result = 99999
for pre_run in range(NUMBER_OF_PRE_RUNS):
    with tf.Session() as presess:

        presess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for pre_iteration in range(NUMBER_OF_PRE_ITERATIONS):
            for batch in range(NUMBER_OF_BATCHES):
                x_batch, y_batch = get_batches(...)
                presess.run(train, feed_dict={x: x_batch, y: y_batch})
            if pre_iteration % 10 == 0:
                # Monitor performance here. Training seems to progress in valid way.
            if pre_iteration == NUMBER_OF_PRE_ITERATIONS - 1:
                pre_result = presess.run(loss_funct, feed_dict={x: all_features, y: all_targets})
                if pre_result < best_pre_result:
                    best_pre_result = pre_result
                    model_path = saver.save(sess=presess, save_path=SAVE_MODEL_PATH)

# tried without the below line, but result was the same.
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())        

    restorer = tf.train.import_meta_graph(SAVE_MODEL_PATH + ".meta")
    restorer.restore(sess=sess, save_path=model_path)

    x_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name='Model_/x:0')
    y_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name='Model_/y:0')
    compute_input_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(name='Model_/input_layer/Tanh')
    # otehr operations & tensors imported here for performance monitoring
    loss_funct_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(name='Model_/loss_f')
    train_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(name='Model_/train')

    for iteration in range(...):
        for batch in range(...):
            x_batch, y_batch = get_batches(...)
            sess.run(train_, feed_dict={x_: x_batch, y_: y_batch})
            # Monitor performance here. All ops result in "None".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tensor do you get None from? If you get None from loss_funct, it is the reason that you used get_operation_by_name for loss_funct. We should use get_tensor_by_name to get a result of a operation.

In the following code, the last line shows None.

```
with tf.variable_scope("model"):
    x = tf.get_variable(name="x", shape=[3], initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal())
    y = tf.reduce_sum(x, name="y")

saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = "./saver"
pre_max = -10000

for i in range(3):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        cur_y = sess.run(y)
        print(cur_y)

        if cur_y > pre_max:
            pre_max = cur_y
            model_path = saver.save(sess=sess, save_path=save_path)

print("max_y : ", pre_max)
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorerer = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_path + ".meta")
    restorerer.restore(sess, save_path)

    y_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(name='model/y:0')
    y_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(name='model/y')

    print(sess.run(y_tensor))
    print(sess.run(y_op))
```

Comment: It worked... one more question, thought. I was able to replace "get_operation_by_name()" with "get_tensor_by_name()" in all cases except for one: the training op. There simply did not seem to be any particular tensor associated, obviously this operation impacts a lot of elements of the model. Yet, the model picked up training despite leaving the line   'train_ = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(name='Model_/train')'   unchanged. Is it because training op doesn't really return any value/ tensor, but modifies model variables instead?

Comment: Yes. training op is not important by itself.  The operations combined with training op modify model variables.